# Disable Cloudformation in Spring Cloud AWS

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-aws

How can I disable the Cloudformation in a spring boot app that using spring cloud AWS?

I keep getting this error when running my app on amazon:

```
...
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.aws.core.env.stack.config.StackResourceRegistryFactoryBean]: Factory method 'stackResourceRegistryFactoryBean' threw exception; nested exception is com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException: Stack for i-b5ce9e32 does not exist (Service: AmazonCloudFormation; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationError; Request ID: 75b3076a-176d-11e6-90cc-b55a643dc6d6)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
        ... 82 more
Caused by: com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException: Stack for i-b5ce9e32 does not exist (Service: AmazonCloudFormation; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationError; Request ID: 75b3076a-176d-11e6-90cc-b55a643dc6d6)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1389)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:902)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.ja
...
```

I doesn't want to use cloudformation. (At least for now.)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I have the following line in my `application.properties` (spring boot) file

```
cloud.aws.stack.auto=false
```

Official documentation: [4.5. CloudFormation configuration in Spring Boot](https://docs.awspring.io/spring-cloud-aws/docs/current/reference/html/index.html#cloudformation-configuration-in-spring-boot)

Comment: Thanks a lot! The second line is not required.

Comment: @LakatosGyula indeed, I just figured out it's for testing locally. Moved it to the local testing profile

Comment: Is this property valid in spring-cloud-aws 3?

Comment: @riteshmaurya https://github.com/awspring/spring-cloud-aws#supported-aws-integrations so far no CloudFormation support so it's not valid as far as I can tell. You can still set static regions etc: https://docs.awspring.io/spring-cloud-aws/docs/3.0.1/reference/html/index.html#region